# Make an element "hide" towards its center?

Tags: jquery, hide, center

I noticed that when using the `hide()` function in JQuery, like this:

`$("myDiv").hide("slow");`

It always "folds" to the top-left corner of the div. Is there a way I could make it fold to the center? (In the case I'm talking about the div is configured `"position: absolute;"`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI has a "scale" effect which might be what you want:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/

http://jsfiddle.net/TzzxZ/1/

Comment: (Hurray for documentation, eh?)

Comment: Thank you! But I'm having a problem with the code. I created a div in html: `<div id="play"></div>` and used [this](http://ideone.com/JNVH7) JS code to hide it after two seconds, but for some reason I get this error: _Uncaught TypeError: Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function_

Comment: found the problem, I didn't know I need to link to the JQuery UI libraries. thanks anyway. :)
And @mblase75, that's a very cool website :O

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 you (still) cannot control where/how the element is scaled down by the hide() function. However, this is how I sorted a similar situation recently:

- html: I wrapped the to-be-hiding-element in a container
- html: I inserted two extra div, one before, one after
- css: I made the container to display:flex
- css: the to-be-hiding element has flex-shrink:2
- css: the two extra div (left and right) each have flex-grow:1

The html markup looks like this

```
<div class='intro'>
  <div class='buffer'>
  <div>
  <div class='text_container'>
    Lorem ipsum, ...
  <div>
  <div class='buffer'>
  <div>
</div>
```

The css looks like this

```
div.intro {
  display: flex;

  div.text_container {
    flex-shrink: 2;
  }
  div.buffer {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

JQuery can now be used to hide the element "towards the center"; ie: the element looks as if it was remaining in the middle.

```
$('.text_container').hide(1000);
```

As a side note, you might want to check flex box adoption against your support requirements https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox In short at the moment of writing this: IE before 10, Opera before 12.1, Opera mobile before 12.1 all aren't going to work; IE11 has a sketchy support.

Oh thank you 2020, you are really sweet!